# Use ISAPI_Rewrite to change subdirectories while preserving the domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

We have two domains, www.aaa.com and www.bbb.com. Both point to the same root directory on the server.

The server has two sub-directories in the root: /abc/ and /xyz/.

If someone types in www.aaa.com/abc/  They should go to /abc/ (like normal)
If someone types in www.aaa.com/xyz/  They should go to /xyz/ (like normal)
** If someone types in www.bbb.com/abc/  They should go to **/xyz/** (using the rewrite)
If someone types in www.bbb.com/xyz/  They should go to /xyz/ (like normal)

How do we write that rewrite for the third case above, where it only affects domain www.bbb.com and not www.aaa.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use condition and a rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^www\.bbb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc$ /xyz [NC,L]
```